# A query blocked by a related_name with Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

It's a Many To Many request but my 'related_name' makes query wrong..

Model :

```
class Course(models.Model):
    subscribed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='course_list', blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={'userprofile__status': 'student'})
```

What I wanted to do :

```
for user in User.objects.filter(editedcourse__in=course_list):
    user.course_list.remove(editedcourse)
```

error :

```
global name 'course_list' is not defined
```

other attempt:

```
editedcourse.subscribed.clear()
```

The `related_name` blocks the access to `subscribed` field.. `acourse.subscribed` is not defined anymore..

I wanted to use both directions but I had problems with query using `__set`.

How can I do my request actually and is it possible all the time to reverse a M2m relation with `__set`?

Comment: How is it "blocked"? How is the query "wrong"? What "problems" did you have? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem has nothing to do with related names. You just have not defined the variable `course_list` before trying to use it in the query. It should be a list of courses you want to match against.

In the second attempt, you still have not explained what you mean by "`related_name` blocks access to `subscribed`". What is `editedcourse`? Where are you getting it from?

**Edit after comment**

> I want to search Users with a course_list that contains 'editedcourse'

Then you are doing things completely the wrong way round. The query you have is "I want to search Users who have an `editedcourse` in a list called "course_list". I guess what you mean is:

```
User.objects.filter(course_list=editedcourse)
```

Comment: First attempt : I am trying to select all users in `subscribed`field. I have defined a related_name, so, I want to search Users with a course_list that contains 'editedcourse'.

Editedcourse is the result of a query like : `Course.objects.get(id=XX)`